# How to properly setStartAngle() in DefultRenderer in AChartEngine?

Tags: android, angle, achartengine

I have created in my application pie chart using AChartEngine. I have written it in this way:

```
private GraphicalView graphicalView;    
private CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("");
private DefaultRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();

private void setUpPieCharts() {
    defaultRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    defaultRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    defaultRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    defaultRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    defaultRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    defaultRenderer.setStartAngle(130);
    defaultRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
    defaultRenderer.setShowLegend(false);

     categorySeries.add("Series " + (categorySeries.getItemCount() + 1), 150);
     SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
     renderer.setColor(COLORS[(categorySeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
     defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

     categorySeries.add("Series " + (categorySeries.getItemCount() + 1), 50);
     renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
     renderer.setColor(COLORS[(categorySeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
     defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_1);
     graphicalView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, categorySeries, defaultRenderer);
     //defaultRenderer.setStartAngle(90);           
     layout.addView(graphicalView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
```

It works quite good. But `setStartAngle()` method seems to be not working. I have tried with few values but my pie chart still looks the same. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

[image: Screenshot with calling this method.]

[image: Screenshot without calling method]

I have uploaded two screenshots with calling and without calling this method. For convenience I have added also this line for my activity:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(defaultRenderer.getStartAngle()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Pie chart still looks the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your code is calling the setStartAngle twice, once with 130 and another time with 90. I think it will always display with start angle = 90.

I have just tried it in the ACE demo application and it works.

OK, I finally managed to see where the issue is. You are running on AChartEngine 1.0.0 which was released in March. The start angle API was there, but it was not working for PieChart and this was fixed in May: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/detail?r=386

In order to have it work, you will have to checkout the AChartEngine code and do a build yourself by running ant dist

Comment: I have tried few options so I have not particularly leave two calls this method. I have deleted the second one, but pie chart still looks the same.

Comment: Please share one screenshot with setStartAngle(130); and one without this call.

Comment: I have shared two screenshot as you wished. Thanks a milion for your interest.

Comment: The pie charts in your screenshots are not rendered by the code you published. Your code adds 2 values: 81 and 19 which means that the big slice should be 81% in size. In your screenshots, the big one is 75%. Do you have the AChartEngine demo on your machine? I can email you the PieChartBuilder.java class containing your code to see how the resulted pie looks like.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am working on one application. I didn't want to publish fragment of its layout. So I have shared the simple activity in which I have been testing AChartEngine. I have updated my code to properly values. Believe me the code is the same. But unfortunatelly pie chart looks the same for few start angle values. I have AChartEngine demo on my phone. I have seen the PieChartBuilder.java before I have started developing my application.

Comment: Are you using AChartEngine 1.0.0?

Comment: See the updated PieChartBuilder.java here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/achartengine/wix24Vq1i30[1-25]

Comment: Yes, I am using AChartEngine 1.0.0 from http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list I have replaced PieChartBuilder.java class in AChartEngine demo in my Eclipse project with your class. I have launched the demo but the result is the same. I have also added handy Toast messages. It is still working in the same way. `setStartAngle()` method seems to be not working. I have additionaly run a Android Virtual Device but the result is the same. I have really got stuck.

Comment: How does the result look like?

Comment: It always looks like start angle has been set to the 0 value. Despite calling `setStartAngle()` method. It looks similar like screenshots I have shared.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15148/discussion-between-dan-and-woyaru)